# How to filter a LINQ query by matching multiple conditions

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

```cs
var userDistricts = db.UserDistricts.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
var availableDistricts = userDistricts.Select(y => y.DistrictId).Distinct().ToList();
var availableStudyYears = userDistricts.Select(y => y.StudyYearId).Distinct().ToList();

// This part doesn't work as-is. Needs to filter down the query based on whether or
// not both district and study year match an entry from the UserDistricts table.
query = query
    .Where(c => availableDistricts.Contains(districtId) &&  
                availableStudyYears.Contains(studyYearId));
```

I have a table called UserDistricts that keeps track of the districts and school years that a student should have access to. Here is an example of data from it...

[image: User Districts Table]

The districts and school years are id's that match up to data in other tables.

I am trying to make a query that filters down another table that contains a lot of data, to only return the ones that a user should have access to by matching both school year and district from the UserDistricts table.

Example: If there are two districts, one called Shady Oaks and one called Sunny Maple, the user may have Shady Oaks 2022, Shady Oaks 2023, Sunny Maple 2019, Sunny Maple 2022. The query originally contains all data for all years for those districts and I need to filter it down to only the data that matches both district and year (the user should not see Sunny Maple 2023 in the query result, for example).

Any help with getting the query part correct?

Comment: Is this a SQL Server?  A relatively simple SQL query would give you exactly the data you need, in the form that you need it.

Comment: Show your model classes.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the queries into one. Instead of querying the districts and study years separately, they must be checked for each entry at the same time.

```cs
query = query
    .Where(
        c => db.UserDistricts.Any(x =>
            x.UserId == userId &&
            x.DistrictId == c.districtId &&
            x.StudyYearId == c.studyYearId)
    );
```

This will also result in a single call to the server instead of three.